# Swipe Gestures and drawing user touches error

Tags: iphone, ipad, touch, gestures

i have UISwipeGestureRecognizer that detects if the user has swiped. i also draw the users touches using the touches moved method found in the tutorial below.

http://www.ifans.com/forums/showthread.php?t=132024

My issue is the gesture seems to override my drawing. is it possible to do both or is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 2):

All of the touches methods get overridden when you invoke a gestureRecognizer. You can view it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in the explanation. It may be best to just write your own code to recognize a gesture if you need all of the touch events for drawing updates. If you still want to use a gestureRecognizer, you can use the `locationInView:` method to find the location of the touch, and then pass those points to your draw method.

I would also think about using OpenglES instead, as it isa bit easier, and you can do more things. There's a great sample project about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLPaint/Introduction/Intro.html). Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks- how do i go about this having used the tutorial i posted above, i would be very grateful for any advice

Comment: I put up some sample code which has methods to do what you want in OpenglES. Also, don't forget to accept answers so that people know this works.